# How do I change the turtle image in Small Basic?

Tags: turtle-graphics, smallbasic

There seem to be no property for an image to use at all, even though it has complete API for movement.

Comment: You're not really Joel Spolsky, are you?

Comment: I would have that moderator diamond after my name if I'm he.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change it at the moment. But according [this forum entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/smallbasic/thread/b8c466b0-b027-4b55-9365-a172ea7e1745), you might be able to do this in later versions.

Comment: Nice, that's what I'm looking for.